# Closing Soft Keyboard in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I found a number of answers to this question but none of them are working for me. I have an Edit text in my Fragment, which gets launched when the application starts. When this Fragment opens, the soft keyboard pops up as well. How do I prevent that from happening? This is what I have in my onCreateView method in my Fragment....

```
        try {
        InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager)getActivity().getSystemService(
                Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
        imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(userName.getWindowToken(), 0);
    }catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: can you please post your XML?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this in `onCreateView` or `onActivityCreated`.

```
getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);
```

Answer (score 1):

My recently project I use the code as follow to hide the keyboard layout, maybe you can try it.(I learn it from the source code of Wordpress-android)

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_template_add_doc, container, false);
    //hide the keyboard if it is visible
    InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity()
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.getApplicationWindowToken(), 0);
    return view;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try the below logics to hide the keyboard from opening automatically.

Try to place your edit text in a separate linearlayout and set `android:focusableInTouchMode="true"`. This will automatically avoids the keyboard opening automatically.

```
  <LinearLayout
     android:id = "@+id/layout"
     android:layout_width = "wrap_content"
     android:layout_height = "wrap_content"
     android:focusable = "true"
     android:focusableInTouchMode = "true">

    <EditText
       android:id = "@+id/edit_text"
       android:layout_width = "match_content"
       android:layout_height = "wrap_content"/>
  </LinearLayout>
```

or if the above fails, hide Programmatically by using the code below. Write it as a separate function and call it in the code.

call this method in your fragment after view is created as below.

```
@Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
     hideKeyboard();
  }

public void hideKeyboard() {
    InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) activity
            .getSystemService(android.content.Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
            activity.getCurrentFocus()
                    .getWindowToken(), 0);
  } // hideKeyboard
```

Good Luck..!

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me,try this way

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {


hideKeyboard(getActivity());
}

    public static void hideKeyboard( Context context ) {

            try {
                InputMethodManager inputManager = ( InputMethodManager ) context.getSystemService( Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE );

                View view = ( (Activity) context ).getCurrentFocus();
                if ( view != null ) {
                    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow( view.getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS );
                }
            } catch ( Exception e ) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:background="@color/background_listview"
android:orientation="vertical">
```

**Using this in Main upper Layout 
    set focusable true and android:focusableInTouchMode true**

**android:focusable="true"**

**android:focusableInTouchMode="true"**

Answer (score 1):

You can also add this line in AndroidManifest.xml to your fragment activity.

line to add:- 
android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"

see code snippet below:-

```
<activity android:name=".activity.FragmentActivity"
       android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Below is working in Kotlin

```
private fun Fragment.hideKeyboard() {
        view?.let { activity?.hideKeyboard(it) }
    }

    fun Activity.hideKeyboard() {
        hideKeyboard(currentFocus ?: View(this))
    }

    private fun Context.hideKeyboard(view: View) {
        val inputMethodManager =
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(view.windowToken, 0)
    }

    private fun Fragment.showKeyboard(et: EditText) {
        view?.let { activity?.showKeyboard(et) }
    }

    private fun Context.showKeyboard(et: EditText) {
        et.requestFocus()
        et.setSelection(et.length()) // This line use to always put cursor at the end of line.
        val inputMethodManager =`enter code here`
            getSystemService(Activity.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE) as InputMethodManager
        inputMethodManager.showSoftInput(et, 0)
    }
```